# How to Protect Sheet on Workbook_Open event with a dynamic password

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim my_code As String
Dim x As Long, y As Integer
Dim Pass_word, Prev_pass As String

my_code = Val(Format(Date, "#")) * 397

Pass_word = create_pass(my_code)

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    wSheet.protect Password:=Pass_word, _
    UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Next wSheet

Exit Sub
errhandler:

x = 1
Do
my_code = Val(Format(Date - x, "#")) * 397
Prev_pass = create_pass(my_code)
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    On Error GoTo move
    wSheet.Unprotect (Prev_pass)
Next wSheet
move:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    x = x + 1
    y = 0
    Err.Clear
Else
    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        wSheet.protect Password:=Pass_word, _
        UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next wSheet
    y = 1
End If
Loop Until y = 1

Resume Next

End Sub
```

What I want to do is to protect sheets inside a workbook with a dynamic password that changes everyday based on the date.
What i'm having trouble with is how to change the set password every day.
I added the `errhandler` routine but it doesn't work.
`create_pass` is a function i created to generate the coded pass and i already tested it and it returns the right value.

Error occurs in this somewhere here:

```
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    On Error GoTo move
    wSheet.Unprotect (Prev_pass)
Next wSheet
```

No line is highlighted so i cannot determine which is it exactly.
I added watch on `Prev_pass` and `x` and it gets the first values then throws up the error.
the returned error is:

```
Run-time error '1004":
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use a `Temp` sheet for this.

Comment: sorry i did not follow. can you explain further Sid? :)

Comment: Sure. Let's say the workbook is protected with 16122013 as a password on 16/12. Now this password will also be stored in a hidden temp sheet. Reason being, if you open the file on the 17th or any other day (could be after 1 year?) then it will read the old password and unprotect the sheet and then protect it again with the new password.

Comment: ok got it. :) clever approach. but why does the code above doesn't work? What i tried to do is to try to unprotect the sheets with a generated pass, then loop otherwise? did i miss something or this approach will really not work?

Comment: The above approach will not work because of what I mentioned in the above post. For protecting a sheet, you will have to unprotect it first if the sheet is protected. And to know the old password, you will have to retrieve it from somewhere or `Hack` it. I would prefer not to discuss `hacking`. Alternatively, you could write a loop to construct passwords which could say loop through last 365 days to create the password and unprotect it. But this will make your code slow.

Comment: yes exactly, that's what i did in the `errhandler` routine. I wrote a loop that contructs a password and tries each and every one of it. But it throws up error instead? i just want to know why the `errhandler` routine above fails. but i'm already working on your suggestion since it is a better approach.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43227/discussion-between-l42-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Why not store the password with SaveSetting() and retrieve it with GetSetting(). You could write an algorithm to hash the password before saving and unhash after getting. Just a suggestion. Is there any downside to this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, we can use a temp sheet which will store the password. And the reason is very simple. let's take this scenario. Let's say the workbook is protected with `16122013` as a password on `16/12`. Now this password will also be stored in a hidden temp sheet. We need to do this because, if you open the file on the `17th` or any other day (could be after 1 year?) then it will read the old password and unprotect the sheet and then protect it again with the new password. For protecting a sheet, you will have to unprotect it first if the sheet is protected. And to know the old password, you will have to retrieve it from somewhere or Hack it.

Here is another method.

This will loop 365 times and try to unprotect your sheet based on your function `create_pass`. I have commented the code so you shouldn't face any problem in understanding it. But if you do then simple post back.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim my_code As String, Ret As String
    Dim PrevDt As Date
    Dim n As Long

    my_code = Val(Format(Date, "#")) * 397

    '~~> Create the password
    Ret = create_pass(my_code)

    '~~> Loop till the password is not found
    Do
        '~~> Attempt to unprotect the sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Ret
        On Error GoTo 0

        '~~> Check if the sheet was unprotected
        If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then Exit Do

        '~~> If not then go back one date
        If PrevDt = #12:00:00 AM# Then PrevDt = Date - 1 Else PrevDt = PrevDt - 1

        my_code = Val(Format(PrevDt, "#")) * 397

        Ret = create_pass(my_code)

        '~~> This counter is required so that we can exit the loop after 365 days
        n = n + 1

        If n > 365 Then
            MsgBox "More than 365 passwords have been checked. Exiting now"
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Edit 1:** (posting the actual Workbook_Open event)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim my_code As String, Ret As String, my_pass As String
Dim PrevDt As Date
Dim n As Long

my_code = Val(Format(Date, "#")) * 397

'~~> Create the password
Ret = create_pass(my_code)
my_pass = Ret

'~~> loop in all WS
For Each ws In Worksheets
    '~~> Loop till the password is not found
    Do
        '~~> Attempt to unprotect the sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Unprotect Ret
        On Error GoTo 0

        '~~> Check if the sheet was unprotected
        If ws.ProtectContents = False Then Exit Do

        '~~> If not then go back one date
        If PrevDt = #12:00:00 AM# Then PrevDt = Date - 1 Else PrevDt = PrevDt - 1

        my_code = Val(Format(PrevDt, "#")) * 397

        Ret = create_pass(my_code)

        '~~> This counter is required so that we can exit
        '~~> the loop after 365 days
        n = n + 1

        If n > 365 Then
            MsgBox "More than 365 passwords have been checked. Exiting now"
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    '~~> protect with the current day password
    ws.protect my_pass, , , , True
Next ws

End Sub
```

This unprotects WS's on opening then protect it with the current password.

Comment: hi sid, i added the actual `Workbook_Open` event code in case someone wants to do the same :). thanks a lot for helping!